# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createConnection

Tags: java, spring, jms

This is my `pom.xml`. I am using Spring 4.3.16.RELEASE version.

```xml
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.uprr.mcs.mse</groupId>
    <artifactId>mse</artifactId>
    <name>mse</name>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
    
        <wicket.version>1.3.5</wicket.version>
        <wicket.spring.annot.version>1.3.5</wicket.spring.annot.version>
        <wickola.version>2.5.3</wickola.version>
        <wickola.jquery.version>2.4.6</wickola.jquery.version>
        <spring.version>4.3.16.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <lib.dir>${project.basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/lib</lib.dir>
        <local.jboss>C:\software\jboss\EWS\1.0\webapps</local.jboss>
        <xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version>2.3.3</xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version>
        <xmlbeans.version>2.4.0</xmlbeans.version>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>local</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${local.jboss}</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>false</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>tomcat-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.1</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <url>http://vx202f.uprr.com:10001/manager/html</url>
                            <username>system</username>
                            <password>tmc4up</password>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        <profile>
            <id>generate-location-bindings-for-find-station</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${xmlbeans-maven-plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <inherited>false</inherited>
                        <configuration>
                            <verbose>true</verbose>
                            <schemaDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/xsd/equipment/locomotive/location</schemaDirectory>
                            <outputJar>${basedir}/lib/find-station-2_1.jar</outputJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
        
        <profile>
          <id>ice-platform</id>
          <build>
            <plugins>
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>com.uprr.ice</groupId>
                    <artifactId>ice-deployer-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.7</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <cluster>ngl-ems-maintenance-schedule-engine-1_0</cluster>
                        <tag>trunk</tag>
                        <archive>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</archive>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin> 
            </plugins>
          </build>
    </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <finalName>ngl#mse#secure#jas</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/java</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.html</include>
                    <include>**/*.png</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
                <filtering>false</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.properties</include>
                    <include>**/*.xml</include>
                    <include>**/*.xsl</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>xmlbeans-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>xmlbeans</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <schemaDirectory>src/main/xsd</schemaDirectory>
                    <outputJar>${lib.dir}/xsd.jar</outputJar>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding>
                    <source>${jdk.version}</source>
                    <target>${jdk.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.12.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <skipTests>true</skipTests>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
    
<!--    <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.enterprise</groupId>
            <artifactId>uprr-diesel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.uprr.enterprise</groupId>
                    <artifactId>uprr-springmvc-http-service-components-autoconfig</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.pojomatic</groupId>
                    <artifactId>pojomatic</artifactId>
                </exclusion>

                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
 -->    
    
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-email</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-extensions</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-guice</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-ioc</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-datetime</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>wickola-components</artifactId>
            <version>${wickola.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.wicket</groupId>
            <artifactId>wicket-spring-annot</artifactId>
            <version>${wicket.spring.annot.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.ui</groupId>
            <artifactId>wickola-jquery</artifactId>
            <version>${wickola.jquery.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.acegisecurity</groupId>
            <artifactId>acegi-security</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.6</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.opensaml</groupId>
            <artifactId>opensaml</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis-jaxrpc</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
            <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
            <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
            <version>3.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
            <version>1.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.54</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
          <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
          <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-modules-cache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
            <!-- <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions> -->
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.santuario</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlsec</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oro</groupId>
            <artifactId>oro</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
            <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
            <version>2.1_3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
            <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
            <version>${xmlbeans.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
        <groupId>com.tibco.ems</groupId>
        <artifactId>tibjms</artifactId>
        <version>8.4.0</version>
        <!-- <version>6.3.0</version> -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>asm</groupId>
            <artifactId>asm-commons</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>1.8.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>equipment-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/equipment-service.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>ricola-wicket</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/ricola-wicket.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsc-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/xsc-client.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/xsd.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app.location.find.system</groupId>
            <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/find-station-2_1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmf2</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/xmf-3_0_1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.components.business-transaction-tracing</groupId>
            <artifactId>business-transaction-tracing-eeb-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.eeb</groupId>
            <artifactId>eeb-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- added for ice migration -->
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.xmf.toolkit</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmf3</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.1</version>
</dependency> -->
        
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-tx -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.6</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

 
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!--end of added for ice migration -->
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.datetime</groupId>
            <artifactId>nc-shared-date-time-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
 
    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.xml-bindings.jaxb2</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-equipment-storage-lifecycle-event</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
  
  <dependency>
  <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.xml-bindings.jaxb2</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-equipment-storage-lifecycle-event</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency> 

<!-- JaxB bindings for event -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.xml-bindings.jaxb2</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb-shared-inspection-dates-changed</artifactId>
  <version>1.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- for CRC7 and system station id -->

 <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.apps.lms.messageprocessor.jaxb</groupId>
            <artifactId>lms-location-invoker-location-find-system-station-2_1</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
         </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            <version>1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.netcontrol.shared.components.business-transaction-tracing</groupId>
            <artifactId>business-transaction-tracing-xmf-toolkit</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.10</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.apps.lms.location</groupId>
            <artifactId>find-system-station-1.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/find-system-station-1.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.apps.lms.service.proxy</groupId>
            <artifactId>phy-common2.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/phy-common2.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.uprr.apps.lms.service.common</groupId>
            <artifactId>serviceProxy2.0</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${lib.dir}/serviceProxy2.0.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springmodules</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-modules-cache</artifactId>
            <version>0.9</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.16.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency> -->

    </dependencies>
</project>
```

When I try to deploy it I am getting:

```
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'serviceListenerContainer'; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.jms.listener.AbstractJmsListeningContainer.createConnection()Ljavax/jms/Connection;
```

Please help me in resolving the issue.

Comment: These error come from the fact you are mixing jars/modules from different versions of a framework. You are using ACEGI security, this is old and deprecated about 10 years ago (maybe longer). Use Spring Securiy, you are also including something Spring Boot related (or a starter) this probably depends on a newer version of Spring. Spring Modules is not maintained and only for an older version of Spring. All in all you are using too old versions of libraries leading to conflicts in your dependencies.

Comment: thank you Mr M. Deinum for your reply. Can you please help me which dependencies i should remove from pom to solve this issue.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "When I try to deploy it"?

Comment: we have our own cloud environment of our client we deploy our application there using one maven command..while i am deploying , i got this error

Comment: Thank you very much - M.Deinum for the solution i removed the ACEGI security and added spring-security instead..it worked fine..its saved my day! Thank you Deinum